# Should we have a blog?

Tags: discussion

Some of the other StackExchange sites have blogs - e.g. [Gaming](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/?blb=1), [Bicycles](http://bicycles.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1), [Photography](http://photo.blogoverflow.com/?blb=1).

**Should we have one?**

**If so, what should be in it?**

Comment: This is currently a Yes/No question, and it will probably only get Yes votes, because who will object? If you don't want a blog, you just won't subscribe to it. A better question might be "What would you like to see as blog content?" and "Who will produce this content?" If we can get agreement on that, it'll be far easier to make this happen. I am particularly concerned that we have enough momentum to get more than 3 articles before petering out.

Comment: A probably better question is "Who wants to write articles for our blog? How often?" and then see if we get enough authors.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes

One thing that would be an excellent thing to blog would be some of our killer answers. I'm thinking a kind of *Mythbusters* style approach:

---

## [Does hot water freeze faster than cold water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3371/922)

#### [luvieere](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3371/does-hot-water-freeze-faster-than-cold-water) asks: [Does hot water freeze faster than cold water?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/3371/922):

> Is it true that hot water freezes faster than cold water and if so, what practical applications have there been found for this phenomenon?

#### [cularis](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/2820/cularis) answers:

> ### Yes
>
> ...In certain circumstances. This is the [Mpemba effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mpemba_effect)
>
> etc. etc.

---

We have a load of well researched informative answers on the site that are almost ready-to-publish blog posts in themselves.

This is something I'd subscribe to!

Comment: This is kind of covered by the automated [weekly newsletter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/what-is-the-weekly-newsletter-who-composes-them). (Please go vote that question up so it becomes a FAQ!)

Comment: @Oddthinking True, but the newsletter will only highlight new content. This will be able to hightlight some of our older gems.

Comment: One topic that might be interesting for a blog is denialism. This could produce a series of articles about different denialist movements, and how they differ from skepticism. It would have to focus on their rhetoric/arguments, rather than their motivation (because we don't question motivation here). Sorry, but I'm not volunteering for this until I have a stable job (~7 years).

Answer (score 2):

## No

A blog might be interesting but maintaining it requires a nontrivial amount of work and the benefit is questionable:

There are already some very prominent skeptics blogs out there with which we basically have no chance of competing. Unless we find a *well-defined niche* which our blog would fill, it does not offer enough value to our site to make it worthwhile.

Additionally, Stack Exchange is already using [Google+](https://plus.google.com/101120115153580954446/posts) as a platform to broadcast interesting questions with some small editorialising. This could be improved and intensified.

(I’m not necessarily convinced that this is true, I just want to put it out here as an alternative to vote on.)